# Can .pop() be used on an array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm writing some code for a class project, and am running into the a problem with the following code:

```
    var sellEverything = function(gold)
{
    console.log("You decide to buy EVERYTHING.");

    var holder;
    while (storeStock.length > 0)
    {
        console.log(storeStock);
        var curItem = storeStock.pop();
        console.log(curItem);
        console.log("You buy a " + curItem.itemName + " for " + curItem.itemPrice + " gold.");
        gold -= curItem.itemPrice;
        console.log(gold + " gold remaining");
    };
};
```

For perspective, storeStock is an array with 6 objects in it. The curItem variable is coming up in the console as undefined, so is it even possible to pop objects off of arrays or is the problem something else?

Here is the data with which storeStock is populated with:

```
    "items":
    [
        {"itemName":"Sword", "itemPrice":100},
        {"itemName":"Bow", "itemPrice":240},
        {"itemName":"Shield", "itemPrice":120},
        {"itemName":"Lance", "itemPrice":300},
        {"itemName":"Potion", "itemPrice":50},
        {"itemName":"Gem of supreme power", "itemPrice":5},
        {"itemName":"Better movie script", "itemPrice":139083882}
    ]
```

Sorry in advance if it's an obvious question.

Edit: Okay, I feel I need to show the entirety of the code for the sake of clarity:

```
var itemList =
{
"items":
    [
        {"itemName":"Sword", "itemPrice":100},
        {"itemName":"Bow", "itemPrice":240},
        {"itemName":"Shield", "itemPrice":120},
        {"itemName":"Lance", "itemPrice":300},
        {"itemName":"Potion", "itemPrice":50},
        {"itemName":"Gem of supreme power", "itemPrice":5},
        {"itemName":"Better movie script", "itemPrice":139083882}
    ]
};

//private class ItemStore
var ItemStore = function()
{
    var storeStock = [];

    //array in function
    var setStockList = function(stockArray)
    {
        if (stockArray instanceof Array)
        {
            var i = stockArray.length;
            for (i; i > 0; i--)
            {
                storeStock.push(stockArray[i]);
            }
            //yes, I could have just done the loop forwards, but wanted to do it this way.
            storeStock.reverse(); 
        };
    };

    //array out function
    var getStockList = function()
    {
        return (storeStock);
    };

    var sellEverything = function(gold)
    {
        console.log("You decide to buy EVERYTHING.");

        var holder;
        while (storeStock.length > 0)
        {
            console.log(storeStock);
            var curItem = storeStock.pop();
            console.log(curItem);
            console.log("You buy a " + curItem.itemName + " for " + curItem.itemPrice + " gold.");
            gold -= curItem.itemPrice;
            console.log(gold + " gold remaining");
        };
    };

    return{
        "setStockList": setStockList,
        "sellEverything": sellEverything,
        "getStockList":getStockList
    };
};
```

Also of note is how I call the setStockList method:

```
    store.setStockList(itemList.items);
```

Comment: Consider: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/sS2fY/

Comment: If the `curItem` variable is showing up as undefined in the console, then you are in the loop. There must be some other code that is causing the problem. If `storeStock` is not an array, then you would get a TypeError in the console because of the call to `pop`.

Comment: _"Can .pop() be used on an array of objects?"_ - The `.pop()` method can be used on any array (and, indeed, on array-like objects via `.call` or `.apply`), regardless of the type of the elements. Remember also that a JS array can hold elements of different types, i.e., some elements might be objects, some might be numbers, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var itemList = {
    items:[
        {itemName: "Sword", itemPrice: 100},
        {itemName: "Bow", itemPrice: 240},
        {itemName: "Shield", itemPrice: 120},
        {itemName: "Lance", itemPrice: 300},
        {itemName: "Potion", itemPrice: 50},
        {itemName: "Gem of supreme power", itemPrice: 5},
        {itemName: "Better movie script", itemPrice: 139083882}
    ]};

//private class ItemStore
var ItemStore = function()
{
    var storeStock = [];

    //array in function
    var setStockList = function(stock)
    {
        if (stock instanceof Array)
        {
            for (var item in stock)
            {
                storeStock.push(stock[item]);
            }

            storeStock.reverse(); 
        };
    };

    //array out function
    var getStockList = function()
    {
        return storeStock;
    };

    var sellEverything = function(gold)
    {
        var holder;

        console.log("You decide to buy EVERYTHING.");

        while (curItem = storeStock.pop())
        {
            console.log(curItem);
            console.log(
                "You buy a " + 
                curItem.itemName + 
                " for " + 
                curItem.itemPrice + 
                " gold."
            );

            gold -= curItem.itemPrice;

            console.log(gold + " gold remaining");
        };
    };

    return {
        setStockList: setStockList,
        sellEverything: sellEverything,
        getStockList: getStockList
    };
};


var store = new ItemStore();
store.setStockList(itemList.items);
console.log(store.getStockList());
store.sellEverything(100000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/sS2fY/3/

Comment: The problem is that for the sake of staying in the rubric of the project, I kinda have to keep the model I have of putting the array in with the pushing.

Comment: See my edit. Are you saying you have to iterate over an object list with a `for` loop (as opposed to a `for each` loop)?

Comment: Note as well your object literal notation is wrong. The labels don't have `"`s around them. See the edit.

Comment: @Tarkenfire - And with a plain `array` iterator: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/sS2fY/4/

Comment: Basically yes. It seems that the answer to most of my problems revolved around the incorrect literal notation, so this does solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: This is a bit closer to your current syntax, with some other cleanup: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/sS2fY/5/ Don't get bit by hoisting (where you have `var`s further down, but they re "hoisted" to the top of the scope as if they were declared at the first of the function block).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `storeStock` is an object that has an `items` array. If so, this should work:

```
var sellEverything = function(gold)
{
    console.log("You decide to buy EVERYTHING.");

    var holder;
    while (storeStock.items.length > 0)
    {
        console.log(storeStock);
        var curItem = storeStock.items.pop();
        console.log(curItem);
        console.log("You buy a " + curItem.itemName + " for " + curItem.itemPrice + " gold.");
        gold -= curItem.itemPrice;
        console.log(gold + " gold remaining");
    };
};
```

Comment: I just edited my post to show more of the code, but suffice to say I populated the array with only the .items stuff before, sorry for causing confusion.

Comment: @Tarkenfire - No worries. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

`storeStock` is an object with `storeStock.items` being the array you want